# ui-view is not rendering the corresponding template for angular-ui-tab?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

ui-view is not working for ui-tab. Please see the scenario, and kindly tell me where I am wrong.

In customers page, I am calling page update customer, by clicking on any customer **customers.view.html**, This page contains the list of customers. When I click on any customer, it open the link like the following url. `http://localhost:3000/home/#/updatecustomer/5`

**customers.view.html**

```
<a><i ui-sref="home.updatecustomer({ customerId: {{customer.id}} })" class="fa fa-edit pull-right" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"></i></a>
```

In config, I am creating the url `http://localhost:3000/home/#/updatecustomer/5`, I am able to open the page index.html, but view corresponding profile and setting is not opening...

Please see the **similar working demo**, [Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiOYgY3NmVmKkPziOeXl?p=preview)

"**config**"

```
.state('home.updatecustomer', {
     url: 'updatecustomer/:customerId',
     views:{
              '':{
                  templateUrl: 'addcustomer/index.html',
                  controller: 'TabsDemoCtrl',
              },
              'profile':{
                  templateUrl: 'addcustomer/profile.html'
              },
              'setting':{
                  templateUrl: 'addcustomer/setting.html'
              },
            }
     })
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app') ;
    app.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', TabsDemoCtrl);
    TabsDemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
    function TabsDemoCtrl($scope, $state){
        $scope.tabs = [
            { title:'profile', view:'profile', active:true },
            { title:'setting', view:'setting', active:false }
        ];
    }
```

**index.html**

```
  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab  ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
        <div ui-view="{{tab.view}}"></div>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

**profile.html**

```
  <div>profile of customer </div>
```

**Setting.html**

```
  <div>Setting for customer </div>
```

Comment: Remove the brackets from ui-view, its not needed. I dont know if this is the problem...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I remove but still not working, I don't thing it will be any problem, Because in working demo, we are using the same thing...

Comment: @geeks Can you please add config also in your plunkr??

Answer (score 1):

There should be `customer.id` without braces in `ui-sref`

```
<a ui-sref="home.updatecustomer({ customerId: customer.id })" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

If you will be able to change your state to `home.updatecustomer` then tabs should work.

**Update**

Fixed attributes:

- passed `ui-sref` to `a` tag
- passed `pull-right` class to `a` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
<a><i ui-sref="home.updatecustomer({ customerId: customer.id })" class="fa fa-edit pull-right" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"></i></a>
```

try this as atn also mentioned I have the same thought hope it helps